# How can I allow Remote Desktop to each computers with individual users through GPO

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to setup AD in my office and I'm facing problem with 'allowing remote desktop'.
We have more than 50 employees and we need to provide computers to each of them.

It's easy to allow all users(or groups) to each computers, **but I have no idea how to configure GPO to allow certain user to certain computer which has to be applied to 50 individual computer.**

For example, If I just wanted to allow more than a single user could logon to a single computer, I could do like this.

> > Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Restricted Groups > Add group to Remote Desktop Users(Built-in)

But in my case, I have to allow only one user to each computers.

**Do I have to create more than 50 policy objects with same configuration only but different users?**
This seems way too inefficient to me.

Is there anything I can try? Plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

in AD, under the tab "Account" there is a button "log on to..." where you can specify the computer that a user can logon to.

Comment: This restricts only the user login to specific nodes, and is nowhere related to Remote Desktop services!